# Getting Juce to Work (Windows)

Tags: c++, juce

I downloaded Juce and VisualStudio2017 because through researches it seemed that Juce was a good way to create a GUI app dealing with midi files.

My problem is i can't even get to use the first examples of GUI !
I get this type of error, for multiple different files :

> [...]\juce\modules\juce_core\native/juce_BasicNativeHeaders.h(135): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wininet.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ....\JuceLibraryCode\include_juce_audio_formats.cpp).

Can anyone help me ?
Looking for this `wininet.h` file into google doesn't appear to give me any help :/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Windows 10 SDK JUCE was targeting by default was broken - multiple files, like `wininet.h` mentioned by you are missing there.

There are a few ways you can fix it:

1) You can get the latest JUCE develop where it is fixed, in particular it was fixed [here](https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/commit/a97bdd635218137be2b8e654058ffd44aea5de87)

2) You can instruct Projucer to use the fixed SDK version by changing **Windows Target Platform** to **10.0.16299.0** (make sure you have the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 and that you have downloaded the Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.16299.0) as shown...

[...here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrTE8.png)

3) You can wait for the new official JUCE release where the fix will be included (i.e. available on master).

Sorry for late response, usually the quickest way to raise any issues is via visiting `forum.juce.com`